# read realtime temperature signals from DAQ to database

Tags: labview

I need to find temperature from certain points in an cylinder through thermocouple. From DAQAssistant  I can read temperature for every 1sec and make a wavegraph at a particular point.

Is it possible

1. to save realtime temperature values(T) in Database for every 1sec. ( eg: in table) ??
2. to take obtained realtime temperature values from that database or table and use it in an function ( eg: x= Y*Z*T) and save the calculated value(X) in 
   another database and make a graph. (eg: T vs X).

Comment: If this is a piece of homework, then yes it is probably possible. Stack Overflow is not a good place for these kinds of questions though, what is expected here is very narrow technical questions

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Please provide what have you tried so far.